# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when adding DataColumn into DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object when I try to add new Column into Datatable. Here is my code:

```
DataColumn clUniqueID = new DataColumn();

clUniqueID.Caption = "UniqueID";
clUniqueID.ColumnName = "UniqueID";
clUniqueID.DataType = typeof(int);
dtMain.Columns.Add(clUniqueID);
```

`dtMain` is a public DataTable. I put this code on form loading in my Win applicatin and when I try to load my form it is throwing Error.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code that initializes `dtMain` and tell us when it is executed.

Comment: Are you sure that you initialize dtMain?

Comment: have you initialized dtMain.
Declaration is not enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make sure that you actually initialize the dtMain:

```
DataTable dtMain; //datatable not initialized, it will be null

DataTable dtMain = new DataTable(); //initialized datatable
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I missed to initialize my datatable.

Answer (score 1):

The other case where one can get null reference during merge is the column names are different, even by case

> You might get null reference exception when the two table have primary
>   keys that differ in only case. [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5169d9c8-631a-4483-b04f-ec539bcb7ca9/datatablemerge-throws-nullreferenceexception?forum=adodotnetdataset)

This was exactly my problem. **The column names of primary keys in both datatables must be same!**

Answer (score 0):

You need to Initialize your DataTable like this:-

```
DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
```

If you have created it like this:-

```
DataTable dtMain;
```

Then its null object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a rather different issue where in the the value items were not available

Consider following:

```
DataTable dtStatusDetails = new DataTable();
    dtStatusDetails.Columns.Add("D1", typeof(string));
    dtStatusDetails.Columns.Add("D2", typeof(string));
dtStatusDetails.Rows.Add(
    data1.Value.ToString(),
    data2.Value.ToString(),
);
```

Here `data1` was of `null` value, and the exception was displaying the same error at line 3 (in this case) line before adding rows.
Putting a null('?') check helped me.

This should be help full if some one forgets a null check